# which features does a network library wrap over the linux network syscalls

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, system-calls

Support we just consider on the Linux platform.

Since the syscalls can provide the epoll/select function, why do we need a C network library？

or in other words, which benefit does a network library offered better than using syscalls directly.

Comment: What network library?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is the OS (on linux) that provides the "syscalls" feature, not the other way around.

Starting from that, to answer your question, libraries are useful for :

- abstracting away low-level OS-bound or API-bound complexity
- working on a higher level of abstraction
- faster and easier development
- easier comprehension of features
- easier knowledge appropriation

and this by providing :

- higher abstraction around concepts/features
- error handling
- error anticipation
- memory management (not always)

A good reading to start with would be :
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html